# How do I get linear acceleration with respect to Earth in Android?

Tags: java, android, rotation, accelerometer, android-sensors

I am creating an application that needs to measure linear acceleration with respect to the Earth and not with respect to the android phone. Is there a system within the SDK that allows this? If not, are there some java libraries that do this? Thanks

```
Type_LINEAR_ACCELERATION
```

only gives acceleration with respect to the device minus gravity.

Comment: The accelerometer measures acceleration of the Android device with respect to the Earth. If your objective is to not remove the gravity, use `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER`. If that is not what you mean, you may wish to explain in greater detail what you mean by "not with respect to the android phone" and "with respect to the device".

Comment: No if device is rotated, the x,y and z axis of device are rotated. So if you turn the device upside down write becomes left up becomes down and so on. How do I get acceleration regardless of which way the device is pointing.